# use associate array total value count Lua

Tags: redis, lua

i want to count the data type of each redis key, I write following code, but run error, how to fix it?

```
local detail = {}
detail.hash = 0
detail.set = 0
detail.string = 0

local match = redis.call('KEYS','*')

for i,v in ipairs(match) do
     local val = redis.call('TYPE',v)
     detail.val = detail.val + 1
end

return detail
```

(error) ERR Error running script (call to f_29ae9e57b4b82e2ae1d5020e418f04fcc98ebef4): @user_script:10: user_script:10: attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'val' (a nil value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that detail.val is nil. That means that there is no table value for key "val". Hence you are not allowed to do any arithmetic operations on it.

Problem a)

`detail.val` is syntactic sugar for `detail["val"]`. So if you expect `val` to be a string the correct way to use it as a table key is `detail[val]`.

Possible problem b)

Doing a quick research I found that this redis call might return a table, not a string. So if `detail[val]` doesn't work check `val`'s type.

Comment: i find why the val is null ,val is a table ,the real value is val.ok = hash or set or other data type ,

Comment: @user1208081, so you would want: `data[val] = (data[val] or 0) + 1`